# Which bug updates are received automatically?

Tags: updates, lubuntu

Please could somebody explain how and when BUG fixes are updated.

I have automatic updating enabled for everything except "Pre-released Updates (Trusty Proposed).  I see that many of the bugs that are bothering me seem to be fixed according to the bug-tracking system, but they are not coming through as updates.

To make this more concrete, I note that PCManFM fails to open a terminal in a folder if that folder name contains spaces. I see that this bug in PCManFM 1.2.0 was fixed in lxsession:
Bug #1314931 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxsession/+bug/1314931

Now I explicitly updated my version of PCManFM to 1.2.3 to get rid of another bug causing hidden files to always be displayed.  Despite the higher version number I still cannot open a terminal in a folder whose name contains spaces.

Also I wonder why I did not get the up-to-date version of PCManFM automatically.  Synaptic did not show it to be available.

Is there something different that I should be doing to get bug fixes more rapidly.  Note that I do not want to chaga later version of Lubuntu.  I am using 14.04 because it is LTS and I want STABILITY, so I am not forever re-installing and fixing software.

Comment: There is [a wiki on SRU](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates)  - Stable Release Updates.

Comment: To respond to your specific issue, the bug report you link to is NOT a bug with PCManFM, but rather with lxsession. As this comment notes - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxsession/+bug/1314931/comments/2 - this bug was fixed in This bug was fixed in the package `lxsession - 0.4.9.2+git20140410-0ubuntu2` - you need to make sure you have that lxsession or newer. Forcing a newer build of PCManFM will never fix an lxsession bug.

Answer (score 0):

When an Ubuntu release is made, the versions of packages/software in that release remain constant. In other words, applications aren't updated just because there's a new version available. The only times there is an update made is when there's a regression from the previous version or when there's a critical vulnerability (some packages have exceptions, like `tzdata`, which contains the timezone information).

Part of an LTS release is that it's *stable*. By changing package/application version, you're making the system *less* stable, as that configuration won't have been tested.

In the bug you referenced, note that the fix was in the `lxsession` package, and bug fixes are always made in the development version of Ubuntu (which was Utopic at that time). If you want it to be in Trusty, someone has to make the case for a [Stable Release Update](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates). See the wiki page for the guidelines and the process.

Answer (score 0):

**Typically, only fixes to critical bugs and security vulnerabilities are pushed down to all users.** The exact definition of a "critical bug" is subject to interpretation, but in general, these would need to be significant problems that affect a large number of users, cause data loss or corruption, or allow someone to exploit your system.

According to the latest package info I can pull from rmadison, if you have a version of Lubuntu that does not include this bug fix (ie an older version of lxsession than 0.4.9.2+git20140410-0ubuntu2), and you say your packages are up to date, you must be running Lubuntu 14.04 LTS.

- (I'm talking about lxsession because the bug you reference is actually an lxsession bug, not one in  PCManFM itself).

**In general, if you want the newest possible software, you should upgrade your system for every new release.** Today, this would mean Utopic (14.10), but in two months, Vivid (15.04) will be released. New versions of packages are tested for stability in the development branch, which is why new versions of Ubuntu include newer, updated software.

- Utopic [has in its suite a newer lxsession package than trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lxsession), which includes a fix to this bug.
- I would not recommend forcing an update to lxsession without updated versions of the rest of LXDE, since these LXDE core packages interact heavily with each other, and forcing an update to one without updating the others could introduce all sorts of unusual behavior on your system (and normal Ubuntu support channels would not be able to help fix this).

The point of LTS release is that it stays stable long-term. The trade off you get for stability means that you will not get the latest packages - only patches on that old version of software or updates that have been [rigorously tested through the stable release update process](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates).

If you want to nominate this package to be released to all users, you could [request a Stable Release Update](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates#Procedure), which would need to be tested in trusty before it would actually go out to users.

In general, Ubuntu's packaging philosophy is intended to prevent new bugs from being introduced while patching old ones. This bugfix - which would patch a relatively minor issue likely affecting a limited number of users - could introduce new bugs that affect other users' existing workflow, no matter how minor a patch it might seem. This is something that has never worked in trusty, so it's at a lower priority than regressions, other bugs that break existing user workflows.

I hope this answers your broad question. I had often wondered this myself when I started using Ubuntu.